# how to groupby the data based on object property in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular

JSON:(Basically I have array of objects. first 3 objects should set into one formgroup so need to convert first 3 objects into 1 objects based on mat_name.id.. edited my question..could you help me to do this??)

```
  const array1 = [{
                   mat_name:{
                             id:1,
                             title:"rose"
                    },
                   month:Mar,
                   year:2020,
                   price:20
                  },
                  {
                   mat_name:{
                             id:1,
                             title:"rose"
                    },
                   month:Apr,
                   year:2020,
                   price:30
                  },
                  {
                   mat_name:{
                             id:1,
                             title:"rose"
                    },
                   month:May,
                   year:2020,
                   price:40
                  },
                  {
                   mat_name:{
                             id:2,
                             title:"jasmine"
                    },
                   month:Mar,
                   year:2020,
                   price:50
                  },
                  {
                   mat_name:{
                             id:2,
                             title:"jasmine"
                    },
                   month:Apr,
                   year:2020,
                   price:60
                   },
                   {
                   mat_name:{
                             id:2,
                             title:"jasmine"
                    },
                   month:May,
                   year:2020,
                   price:80
                   }      
                 ];
```

Conversion Json:(Above array should do like this based on month, year and mat_name.. )

```
       const array1 = [
                       {
                       mat_name:'Rose',
                       mat_id:1,
                       price1:20,
                       price2:30,
                       price3:40
                        },
                         {
                       mat_name:'Jasmine',
                       mat_id: 2,
                       price1:50,
                       price2:60,
                       price3:80
                        },
                         ]
```

Comment: please add your try.

Comment: Take a look at the array functions (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).  For example filter. Then think about your goals "price1", "price2" will make your code complicated. Perhaps think about an array of prices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with an ES6 [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to group all your prices. Here, the map uses `mat_name` as its key and an array of prices associated with that `mat_name` as its value. By passing this map into [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) as the first argument, and providing a mapping function as the second, you can map each key-value pair in the array to objects. The object can contain the `mat_name`, along with the prices from the array (merged using [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)):

```js
const arr = [{ mat_name: 'Rose', month: 'Mar', year: 2020, price: 20 }, { mat_name: 'Rose', month: 'Apr', year: 2020, price: 30 }, { mat_name: 'Rose', month: 'May', year: 2020, price: 40 }, { mat_name: 'Jasmine', month: 'Mar', year: 2020, price: 50 }, { mat_name: 'Jasmine', month: 'Apr', year: 2020, price: 60 }, { mat_name: 'Jasmine', month: 'May', year: 2020, price: 80 } ];

const res = Array.from(
  arr.reduce((m, {mat_name, price}) =>
    m.set(mat_name, [...(m.get(mat_name) || []), price]), new Map), 
  ([mat_name, prices]) => 
    Object.assign({mat_name}, ...prices.map((p, i) => ({['price'+(i+1)]: p})))
);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: I need one more concern if the month will be changed, data should be remain.. right?? How we can make based on month and year it takes the value dynamically??